# Android: Unable to perform a task repeatedly using android service

Tags: android, android-service

I have written a service in android.I want to repeatedly perform a task using service. That is the service shouldn't die and should perform the task repeatedly. However,the service performs the task just once and then gets killed.How to perform the task repeatedly in background.
My current code is->

```
public class SyncService extends Service {

    private Looper mServiceLooper;
    private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
// Start up the thread running the service.  Note that we create a
// separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
// main thread, which we don't want to block.  We also make it
// background priority so CPU-intensive work will not disrupt our UI.
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        thread.start();

// Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
        mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(SyncService.this, "servicestarting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = startId;
        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // We don't provide binding, so return null
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(SyncService.this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // Handler that receives messages from the thread
    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Toast.makeText(SyncService.this, "repeatedly perform some task", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //constantly perform task here

        }
    }
}
```

How to repeatedly perform some task using service?

Answer (score 2):

Well you only send one message to the Handler.  So that message will be processed once.  You could have the Handler pass the same message back again, but with no delay that isn't a good idea-  you'll deadlock the main thread.  The best way to do something repeatedly would be to spin off a Thread and do it in the Thread, with the Thread's Runnable looping forever.